# Dropbox API v2 JavaScript read file

Tags: javascript, api, dropbox

I would like to use Dropbox's JavaScript API (v2) to read the content of a text file from Dropbox, from what I know the closest method is `filesDownload()`. suppose we have a test.txt file in the root folder with the content 'abc'. my JavaScript code would look like the following (I use webpack)

```
var Dropbox = require('dropbox');
var dbx = new Dropbox({accessToken: '...'});

dbx.filesDownload({path: '/test.txt'})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

an object is actually returned, with the following content

```
Object {
    client_modified: "2017-03-06T06:34:24Z"
    content_hash: "f62f4917741f7ed26e883d8193ddf477cde87b99dfbd8d5d8f67eb400087e0b6"
    ...
}
```

but there is no file content (e.g. "abc") in the returned object. instead, when I inspect the network tab of the chrome browser console, I can see the file named "download" with the url "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download" which has the content "abc".

My question is, how can I actually get the content of the file? (Once I can get the content then it is easy to show them in the webpage)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

oh, i figure out how to get the content of the file. 
the returned object actually includes a fileBlob object

```
Object
    client_modified: "2017-03-06T06:34:24Z"
    ....
    fileBlob: Blob
        size: 5
        type: "application/octet-stream"
        __proto__: Blob
            ...
```

and you can use browser's fileReader to get the content out. so the complete code would look like the following

```
var Dropbox = require('dropbox');
var dbx = new Dropbox({accessToken: '...'});

dbx.filesDownload({path: '/test.txt'})
    .then(function (response) {
        var blob = response.fileBlob;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
            console.log(reader.result); // will print out file content
        });
        reader.readAsText(blob);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        ...
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me! By the way, in my case I used `response.result.fileBlob` instead of `response.fileBlob`