# Display .txt file's content in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropbox-api

I'm looking to display the contents of a .txt file stored in dropbox via the dropbox API.

I'm already pulling through and displaying images by creating src url blobs

All of the examples I've found through researching either use jQuery or ajax. Since I'm already accessing these files through the API surely there isn't a need for another call up to the dropbox server?

I've tried to use the `embed` tag but the browser then tries to download the file.

**How do you display a txt file's content in react using the Dropbox API?**

```
class Project extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    fileSource: [],
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  var that = this;
  var sources = [];
  var link = "/"+this.props.title;

  dbx.filesListFolder({path: link})
    .then(function(response) {

      ...
      ...
      //call to dropbox
      ...
      ...

        var newUrls=window.URL.createObjectURL(response.fileBlob);
        sources.push(newUrls);
    })

    .then(function(){
        that.setState({
          fileSource: sources,
        });

      });
    }
  });
}

render() {

  if(!this.state.fileSource.length)
    return null;

    let text = this.state.fileSource.map((el, i) =>
      <embed src={el}/>
    )

    return (
      <div className="projectWrapper">
        {text}
      </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code shows you using `filesListFolder`, which returns file metadata. If you want the file content, you'll need to call [`filesDownload`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload__anchor) for the desired file(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropbox API v2 JavaScript read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622526/dropbox-api-v2-javascript-read-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622526/dropbox-api-v2-javascript-read-file) previous question which creates a fileBlob from the object and then uses `FileReader()` and `readAsText()` to display the contents.